# Hamiltonian of two consecutive identical beam splitters

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-optics

If the Hamiltonian of a single beam splitter is

$$H = \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}} \left( a^\dagger b - b^\dagger a \right),$$

what is the Hamiltonian of two consecutive beam splitters? Is this trivial?

Comment: Is it intentional that the Hamiltonian is anti-hermitian? (which implies dissipation).

Comment: Whoops, my mistake

Comment: While the notation may be standard it would help if you would specify what state creators/annihaltors refer to. I guess the lowest cavity mode right and left of the beam splitter? Or simple the right/left-moving state in some approximation for the dynamic problem? If we talk about modes in a cavity, then you have to add another creator/annihilator pair for another state and just add the Hamiltonians for the two beam splitters (connecting (a, b) and connecting (b, c)).

Comment: I agree with @SebastianRiese that the question needs more details, e.g., about the configuration of the two beamsplitters. In its present form answering requires a lot of guesswork.